# How can I get user information from facebook,twitter... with using OAuth in mvc4

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

Anyone have any idea about getting contacts,user information like where he is working and where he is  from for facebook, twitter, linkedin..... in mvc4

Comment: What problem are you having? Any code samples?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case. If your use case includes a third-party login with the providers mentioned above you can use [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity). With Identity you can retrieve user informations from Facebook, Twitter, Google, and from a Microsoft account. Other providers, like LinkedIn, must be added separatly.

Otherwise you have to look for separate framework, which can f.e. access the Graph API of Facebook.

Keep in mind that the user must give you access to this information.

Comment: I am getting only user id, gender, link, email of that user with using OAuth in mvc4 here i want to know where the user is working and his friends profile information also

Comment: Then you have to go with specialized frameworks which can work with the interface of the appropriate provider. You will find most of them on Codeplex and GitHub. But, like I said, most of the time you won't get the data you'll need, especially when it comes to the data of persons related to a person. This really depends on the privacy settings of the user (f.e. in Facebook or LinkedIn).